# If Then Block using SnowSQL in snowflake

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bteq

Is there a way to achieve If then computational logic  using snowsql commands like we
have in Teradata Bteq Commands as below:

```
    .if 1 >= 0 then select department_id from department;
    .if ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 then select employee_id from employee
```

Comment: You can either use Snowflake UDF or a bash script to do this.

Comment: As Simon says, the quick answer is yes. But can you give us more context on the environment and desired results for your question?